# Flex RSL Understanding

Tags: apache-flex, rsl

Till now I was using "Merged into code" for "Framework Linkage" in
Flex Builder. Now, I changed it to "Runtime shared library". On doing
a release build I got myapp.swf which is roughly 260 KB which was earlier
close to 350 KB.  It also generated **framework.swz** and framework.swf.
But I copied only myapp.swf on my web site and not **framework.swz**.

Still the website works just fine. I also cleared the flash player cache
from [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager07.html). It works just fine without the .swz file. So my questions are:

Is the **framework.swz** file actually used or does the flash player have
a copy of it beforehand. And is that copy not cleared by clearing cache of
flash player?

And, even after clearing the cache, I didn't see a request for **framework.swz**
in firebug. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The framework.swz RSL is stored in a special Flash Player cache.  It works cross-domain.  You will definitely need the framework.swz file there for those that don't yet have the RSL in their cache.  On Linux the cache is at: .adobe/Flash_Player/AssetCache

Also, if you are not already doing so, make sure you do a Export Release Build for your production app.  That will reduce the size further.

Comment: Hi James,  
Thanks.  
On Windows the path is :  
C:\Documents and Settings{username}\Application Data\Adobe\Flash Player\AssetCache\YL8MBYGY  
Once I deleted the files in the above folder  
firebug did show a request being sent for  
framework.swz.  


Note: The folder Application Data might be a hidden folder.  
So you may need to perform some extra steps to get to it.